# Playing Multiple Portions of You Tube Video

Tags: youtube

I know, we can start playing a youtube video at any minute as Youtube provides the api.

What I want is, I want to play multiple portions of the video. For example in a video I want to play from minute 1 to 2, then again from minute 5 to 10 and again from minute 43 to 54.

Is there an API or tool for doing that.

One thing I thought was creating different videos & put them as a play list, but not sure how faster will it be.

Let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

[#Getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) shows an example of a video being played for 6 seconds from the beginning before it stops.

[#seekTo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo) allows advancement of video playback.

You may also use [#loadVideoById](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById) to pass in the start time and end time via the object syntax, although this method may require the loading of the same video multiple times.